# PHP Convert Date/Time format from 'd/m/Y H:i:s' to 'H:i:s'?

Tags: php, date, time, string-formatting, strtotime

I have a timestamp column in my database with dates and times formatted like '24/06/2015 14:30', but I need to convert it to just '14:30'. I've tried everything please help.

Comment: `$test = explode(" ",$date);echo $test[1];`

Comment: I've tred the following code in many different ways and $time always comes up blank.                                                                                  $stamp = $row['Timestamp'];
$time = strtotime($stamp);

Comment: Timestamp column in database is not formatted. It is just timestamp. Show how you convert timestamp to String and someone tell you how to get expected formatting

Answer (score 0):

Very easy to use, just pass in argument and format: http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php